# Need my data to fit ANOVA...

Tags: analysis, statistics

I am doing some research on constructed wetlands. I have four wetland 
 as follows.

1. Wetland A - Gravels
2. Wetland B - Gravels + Plant
3. Wetland C - Biochar + Plant
4. Wetland D - Biochar + Gravels + Plants

I need to find if there is any effect of bio-char in reducing the contaminants (Total Nitrogen, Total Phosphorus, etc).

I record the initial value (influent concentration) and after 5 day again I record final value (effluent concentration).

So I have data of 8 run for all the four wetlands for parameters like Total nitrogen, Total Phosphorus etc.

I now want to do ANOVA to find if biochar is efficient enough to reduce the contaminants.

But I dont know how to fit my data for ANOVA.

Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Can u elaborate mor on the experiment (just to get a better impression)? What are ur samples (the soil, plants, gravels, ..)? Can the N, P, etc. measurements be assumed to be independent (u ask for each of the cases N, P, .. if biochar can reduce it and they are not influencing each other)? If this is true u would like to do single factor otherwise multiple factor ANOVA. How often do u repeat ur measurements (as u describe it sounds as if u do for each type like N, P, .. one measurement in beginning and one more after 5 days, so u end up with 8 for each - that would be not sufficient?).

Comment: @YonedaLemma  Basically I have 3 type of wetland one with gravels, one with biochar and one with biochar+gravels (1:1) ratio. I have retention time of 5 days (Hydraulic retention time). I am doing experiment in batch wise. So I am saturating the wetland with wastewater, taking zero day reading (N, P) and after end of 5 day final reading (N, P). The cycle stops at end of 5 days. Again I re-saturate the wetland with new waste water. In this way I have data for 8 batches (8 week data).

Answer (score 0):

ANOVA calculates and compares the variances of a series of point clouds.

Say we regard $(N,P)$ measurements.

As I understand, you have $n$ sites $S_1,..,S_n$ (some with some without biochar).
Your basic experiment for each site would then be one measurement of $N$ and $P$ at start and one other measurement after 5 days, and your dependent variable $X$ would be the difference $(\delta^N, \delta^P)=:\delta$ of these two $(N,P)$ measurements?

If for each site $S_i\space (i=1,..,n)$ you repeat this experiment $m=8$ times you come out for each with $\delta^i_1,..,\delta^i_m$ - your $i_{th}$ point cloud.

So as far as I understand, your experiment is suitable for a variance analysis (further necessary conditions for your data, like normal distributed residuals, are usually checked by the statistic SW u use).